# Unable to fetch the result for this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
CREATE TABLE Seller
(
    Seller_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(20),
    Address varchar(30),
    ContactNo varchar(20),
    EmailAddress varchar(30)
)

CREATE TABLE Buyer
(
    Buyer_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(20),
    Address varchar(30),
    ContactNo varchar(20),
    EmailAddress varchar(30)
)

CREATE TABLE Property 
(
    Property_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Address varchar(100),
    YearBuilt int ,
    Area int ,
    NoOfRooms int,
    NoOfBathrooms int
)

CREATE TABLE Property_Office
(
    Office_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Office_subrub varchar(100),
    Address varchar(200),
    TelephoneNumber varchar(20),
)

CREATE TABLE Staff 
(
    Staff_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(20),
    Gender varchar(1),
    Salary int,
    CommissionPercent int,
    HiredDate date,
    MobilePhoneNumber varchar(20),
    EmailAddress varchar(30),
    Property_ID int,

    CONSTRAINT chk_Commision_perc CHECK (CommissionPercent <= 20),
    CONSTRAINT fk_property_off  
        FOREIGN KEY (Property_ID) REFERENCES Property_Office(Office_id)
)

CREATE TABLE Listing 
(
    Listing_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    DateListed date,
    ListPrice int,
    DateSold date,
    PriceSold int ,
    Seller_ID int ,
    Property_ID int,
    Pro_Office_Id int, 
    Staff_Id int,

    CONSTRAINT fk_Seller_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (Seller_ID) REFERENCES Seller(Seller_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Property_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (Property_ID) REFERENCES Property(Property_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_property_office 
        FOREIGN KEY (Pro_Office_Id) REFERENCES Property_Office(Office_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Satf_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (Staff_Id) REFERENCES Staff(Staff_Id)
)

CREATE TABLE listing_sold
(
    Serial_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Listing_ID int,
    Buyer_ID int ,
    Property_ID int ,
    Staff_Id int,
    Seller_Id int,

    CONSTRAINT fk_buyer_listing_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (Listing_ID) REFERENCES Listing(Listing_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Buy_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (Buyer_ID) REFERENCE SBuyer(Buyer_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_propt_off 
        FOREIGN KEY (Property_ID) REFERENCES Property_Office(Office_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Satff 
        FOREIGN KEY (Staff_Id) REFERENCES Staff(Staff_Id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_ls_Seller_Id 
        FOREIGN KEY (Seller_Id) REFERENCES Seller(Seller_Id),
)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can get this below result from these tables

1. List offices where the number of its listings that have not been sold is 2 times more than the number of staff in that office. Display the office suburb and the total number of listings for sale in the office.

I am facing issues while trying this query. The problem here is how to make a comparison of listings with the staff length within the same office.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

```
select Q.subrub As Subrub ,T.NumberOfSoldedListsForOffice as SN
from
    (select count(listing_sold.Seller_Id) as NumberOfSellersInOfFice,Property_Office.Office_subrub as subrub,Property_Office.Office_id as id
        from listing_sold ,Property_Office
        where Property_Office.Office_id=listing_sold.Property_ID
        group by Property_Office.Office_subrub ,Property_Office.Office_id
    )Q
    inner join
    (select count(listing_Sold.Listing_Id) as NumberOfSoldedListsForOffice,Property_Office.Office_id as id
        from listing_sold ,Property_Office
        where Property_Office.Office_id=listing_sold.Property_ID
        group by Property_Office.Office_id 
    )T
on T.id=Q.id
where Q.id=T.id And T.NumberOfSoldedListsForOffice = 2*Q.NumberOfSellersInOfFice
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 264
Column 'Property_Office.Office_subrub' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Add Group by Q.Office_subrub at the end of query

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 322
Column 'Property_Office.Office_subrub' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Still an Error .

Comment: i edited code it's ok but you didn't have any office with those properties.
if you check your data, you can't find any office with those properties.